# DatabaseCrawler override no longer works after upgrade from Sitecore 7.2 to 9

Tags: content-search, upgrade

In 7.2, Below function AddAllFields was overridden for a custom search implementation.

```
public class DatabaseCrawler : Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler
{
    protected override void AddAllFields(Document document, Item item, bool versionSpecific)
    {
        base.AddAllFields(document, item, versionSpecific);
        foreach (DatabaseCrawler.StoredField current in this._storedFields)
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field = item.Fields[current.SitecoreFieldName];
            if (field != null)
            {
                FieldCrawlerBase fieldCrawler = FieldCrawlerFactory.GetFieldCrawler(field);
                Assert.IsNotNull(fieldCrawler, "fieldCrawler");
                document.Add(base.CreateDataField(current.FieldName, fieldCrawler.GetValue()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to achieve the same in Sitecore 9?

Comment: Can you add more info about what that actually does? If it's just to index all fields, then this is the default out of the box functionality in Sitecore 9.

Comment: Above function used nowhere. Seems, it's just been added to index all fields.